# Using sp_send_dbmail with SQL authentication to send attachments from UNC path

Tags: sql-server-2016, credentials

I'm trying to send emails with attachments using a SQL authentication account that I have granted [credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/credentials-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) to.

The login used in the stored Credentials is a domain account that has permissions to read from the share.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients = 'me@abc.xyz.nz', 
    @profile_name = 'Alarms', 
    @subject = 'Test with Attachment', 
    @body = '*** Alarms ***' , 
    @file_attachments = '\\Servername\Share\Images\TestImage.png'
```

But when I use the SQL login I get the following error:

> Msg 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 The client connection security
>   context could not be impersonated. Attaching files require an
>   integrated client login

What have I missed? how can I test that the credentials have been applied correctly? Does this only work for a local share?

Edit: I granted my SQL login Sysadmin privs and it now works with both a local share and with a remote share. So what privs does sysadmin have that allows this to work?

Comment: What account did you define in your profile?

Comment: @StijnWynants In the email profile I was using anonymous login. I tried using "windows authentication using db engine service credentials" but it made no difference. (also tried providing basic logins with no luck.)

Comment: Question edited. Have found this works with syadmin privs. But I don;t want that acct to have sysadmin. So what specific privs do I need to grant to the sql login?

Comment: Are you sending the email inside a job? or you run the sp_send_dbmail manually after you log in as that sql login account?

Comment: @jyao  For testing/debugging I am running it from SSMS

Comment: I would suggest that you turn on xp_cmdshell temporarily and just do a `xp_cmdshell 'dir <your file location>'` and see whether it is indeed your account issue or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working eventually in my Dev environment.

1. Enable xp_cmdshell
2. Add proxy account DomainLogin
3. grant execute on xp_cmdshell to SQLLogin
4. Grant logon as a batch job on Server 
   On server open Secpol. > Security Settings > Local Policies – User Rights Assignment node. Add DomainLogin
5. Create SQL Credential "CredForMail" using DomainLogin
6. Grant Credential to : ALTER LOGIN SQLLogin ADD CREDENTIAL CredForMail
7. ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET TRUSTWORTHY ON

The end result is that I have a non-sysadmin user that can send emails with attachments it has picked up from a share on a remote server.

I think the proxy account and Credential may be overlapping and both may not be necesary. I have tried so many things I am no-longer sure of the bare minimum required to make this work. (and that bothers me)

Because of the complexity to set this up, enabling features that could be seen as a security risk, I am going to back all of this out, and instead will separate out this application function and give it it's own domain account.